# error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant: std::array and std::vector size allocation

Tags: c++, macros

The error stems from macro definition in my code:

```
#define NUM_ROWS 3
```

The following is the pastebin link to complete source code:

[Complete Source Code](https://pastebin.com/Zar1nypj)

The compilation error is

```
code.cpp:14:18: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define NUM_ROWS 3
                  ^
code.cpp:19:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUM_ROWS’
 vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>>(NUM_ROWS) matrix;
                             ^~~~~~~~
code.cpp:14:18: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
 #define NUM_ROWS 3
                  ^
```

The following is the pastebin link to the compiler log:

[Compiler log](https://pastebin.com/V964XkEh)

I have looked up related errors on Stack Overflow but the contexts seem different in the case of those errors. In this case, I intend to use the macros to pre-define the size of the `std::array` and `std::vector` objects. I thought of using macros since my understanding is that I should use constants for the sizes.

Appreciate your thoughts

Comment: vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>>(NUM_ROWS) matrix is wrong, try vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>> matrix(NUM_ROWS)

Comment: " I thought of using macros since my understanding is that I should use constants for the sizes. " when you need constants you should use constants not macros. What's wrong about `const int num_rows = 3;` ?

Comment: Please include the code and errors in the question. Links can break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers that might help you:

```
vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>>(NUM_ROWS) matrix;
```

is wrong, the proper way to construct a `std::vector` having `NUM_ROWS` elements is

```
vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>> matrix(NUM_ROWS);
```

Secondly, I watched your code (you might want to add it to the question for posterity)

```
void set_matrix(vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>>(NUM_ROWS)&)
```

and similarly defined functions, will not work `NUM_ROWS` is not part of the type of `vector`, try

```
void set_matrix(vector<array<int,NUM_COLS>>&)
```